# What does the line on top of variables in deferential equations mean?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, notation

For example,

[equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LL83w.png)

What does the horizontal line on top of *f* mean?

Comment: It is a *differential* equation. "Deferential" means showing respect, deference

Comment: And A) That is not a differential equation B) $\overline{f}$ has many meanings dependent on context - since the author used $\mathrm{Var}$ it is clearly the case that $\overline{f}$ is the expected value

Comment: Before asking such a question, you can give context, often if you read the context you can find your answer, and for a second remark you can paste pictures directly into the question body. f with the bar often means the conjugate of f, f being a complex function

Answer (score 1):

In that context, being $g$ a set $g=\{g_1,g_2,...,g_n\},$ it means

$$\overline{g}=\sum_{i=1}^n g_i x_i.$$

It is a weighted expected value, where each element $g_i$ has a weight $x_i$.